# How can I control where an item is placed in a dynamically rendered EJS list?

Tags: javascript, css, server, ejs

I have an `<ol>` in EJS that consists of info obtained from objects in a database. As I make new objects, the list gets a new `<li>` with their information. These objects all have a date as their first field.

Is it possible to have the `<ol>` sort itself chronologically based on this date field? i.e., nearest date is '1' in the list, but if an object with an earlier date is added it will become '1' and the previous near date becomes '2'. The date is also contained in its own `<span>` within the list.

Here's what my EJS is looking like for now:

```
    <ol class="shows">
    <% for(let i=0; i < info.length; i++) {%>
        <li class="show">
            <span class="bold"><%= info[i].date %></span><span>  </span><span><%= info[i].bands %></span><span> - </span><span><%= info[i].venue %></span><span> - </span><span><%= info[i].ticketPrice %></span><span> - </span><span><%= info[i].startTime %></span><span> - </span><span><a href="<%= info[i].ticketLink %>">♣</a></span>
        </li>
    <% } %>
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply sort your array...

```
info.sort((a,b)=> b-a)
```

Comment: You could also sort it server side... But if you add them dynamically on the front side, then you'd need to resort or put the new items in the correct place. There's no magic, the for loop simply goes through the items in order they are, so if you change your order you change the order of display.

Comment: D'oh, still new with backend so sometimes completely obvious stuff escapes me - thanks for your answer!